# init, alloc and retain and "the initial value is never read"

Tags: objective-c, ios

Ive have used the static analyser to look through my code and have arrived at the following question.

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
string = [object name];
```

This give me a memory error saying that the initial value is never read.
I replaced it with the following

```
NSString *string = [[object name]retain];
```

Is this better/correct coding?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen someone else do this exact thing. `NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];` creates a new object and assigns it to string. `string = [object name];` Assigns the name of `object` to string. It is similar to saying `int a = 0; a = 4`, `0` has no effect on the `4`. The problem with your code is that `[[NSString alloc] init]` creates a new object with a retain count of 1, because you do not release it it leaks. `[object name]` returns an autoreleased object which will disappear at the end of the runloop.

In short, use `NSString *string = [[object name] retain];`

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
1: NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
2: string = [object name];
```

is incorrect because in line **1:** you allocate new memory and store reference to it in variable `string`. In line **2:** you store in variable `string` reference to another memory location.

As a result, you didn't read memory value that was allocated at line **1:** and even didn't `release` it. So moreover you have memory leak there.

If you want to save reference to some place in memory you don't need `alloc+init`. You should use `alloc+init` when you want to allocate some space in memory where you will write data or read from.

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `string` is actually a *pointer* to an `NSString` object.  The first line of your code created a new empty string and assigned a pointer to it to `string`.  The second line of code then immediately overwrites that pointer with a pointer to a completely different string.  You have never read the original value, and there is no way to access the allocated `NSString`, thus it has leaked.

The second option is correct., provided you release/autorelease it somewhere later.